# Impact of BASH bug on Azure Websites, Cloud Services and SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, shellshock-bash-bug

Just been reading about this potentially serious Linux based bug. It would seem that Azure should be on the safe side, as being Windows based, and most likely quickly patched, as that is why we use Platform As A Service (PAAS).

For anybody wondering what this is all about Try Hunt has a good article at: [Troy Hunt's Article](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about.html)

Any comments from anyone on this, or pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: RE: "professional server- ...." - I design and develop ASP.NET applications to deploy on Azure. As a developer I want to know that Azure is covered with regard to Bash, and I am extremely pleased that BilalAlam, from MS's Azure team, has responded, to say that their admins have done their work well, and we, as developers, need not worry. So I guess I do see this as highly relevant to devs, and hence why the points on Bilal's answer is increasing. My question is answered, so I do not propose to reopen,but I would hope others can benefit - I am happy and very grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure WebSites is safe with respect to ShellShock.  Azure WebSites uses IIS as our web server and we do not expose any external anonymously-accessible endpoint which exposes/calls Bash.

Note that we do install Bash as part of our VM installation (it comes with Git).  But we do not expose any vector for calling into this shell remote/anonymously.  We will be updating Bash for caution-sake.

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative reply. I am sure this will be most reassuring for many Azure developers.